# Find Syncword (pattern) in signal, using Correlation

Tags: matlab, noise, correlation, preamble

I have a signal which always has the same syncword ([93 0b 51 de] in hexa).

I also have a signal with additive noise(attacing it, and I want to find my syncword in that a noisy signal using corelation(actually using xcross corelation), I attach the plot of my signal with additive noise(actually the demodulated signal that I de modulated it), my syncword is hidden here with noised signal and other data(like crc ..but doesn't matter for me and Im just looking for my syncword)
[image]

those data Im getting from transmitter that's transmiting on frequency 868MHZ , Im implicitly the receiver and sampling in frequency 868MHz , those IQ samples data has packets and Im seeing them on my matlab
[image]

those IQ samples data(sampling them on 20480000) I demodulated them by two matched filters and the data the I got is ranges between 1 , -1 . -1 means 0 in binary and 1 means 1 in binary.. (the plot of my demodulated data see the first photo that I attached above..

code in matlab:

```
>>fs=204800;
>>dk=loadFile('fm.dat'); %Im loading the IQ samples that I sampled them by my hardware sampler , once I do plot(real(dk)) I see the packets in matlab 

>> t20=[-40000:40000]*(1/fs);
>> mf1200 = 100*exp(i*2*pi*t20*100000);
>> mf2200 = 100*exp(i*2*pi*t20*-100000);
>> d12 = conv(dk,mf1200,'same');
>> d22 = conv(dk,mf2200,'same');
>> ddif=((abs(d12)-abs(d22))./(abs(d12)+abs(d22)));
>> xCorrResult=xcorr(ddif',random);
```

Then I used xcorr, but I was a little confused by that. Can you help me? It looks like that signal was too noisy so that no syncword was found in my demodulated data that ranges between (-1 1) ?
[image]

the packet that I transmit is in frequency 868MHZ, 50KHZ symbol rate , deviation 100KHZ , and my syncword/data are attached in the photo below:
[image]

the file can be opened on matlab by this matlab code (plot(real(y) will give you plot of packets like nullPacketDatanullPacketDatanullPacketData):

```
function y = loadFile(filename)
%  y = loadFile(filename)
%

% reads  complex samples from the rtlsdr file
%

fid = fopen(filename,'rb');
y = fread(fid,'uint8=>double');

y = y-127.5;
y = y(1:2:end) + i*y(2:2:end);
```

Comment: It looks like you are clearly seeing something-- those big spikes in the correlation suggest that is where the syncwords are located.

Comment: @DanBoschen not but those big spikes isn't properly .. because In my photo Im displaying just one packet .. and it should be just one big spike but here in the plot found 2+ big spikes .. so the result/the plot isn't good

Comment: @DanBoschen would be really appreciated if you could help me to do my xcross corelation to be more readable and more clear .. I guess the problem in my demodulator(two exponent-the two matched filter..)

Comment: @DanBoschen Im transmit the packet in frequency 868MHZ , deviation 100khz , symbol rate 50Kbaud , so the sampler (my dongle) is sampling on that frequency .. and I get IQ samples raw data , I put my two matched filter on frequency 100000 in my exp because the receiver will get the packet data on +-100khz  and on 868khz will be zero ..

Comment: for your wish I explain here: I send RF packets in frequency 868MHZ and symbol rate 50KHZ (symbol rate=bit rate) , deviation is 100kHZ , so once I transmit by cc1350 hardware of texas instrument, and Im sampling those IQ SAMPLES DATA (raw data) by a sampler called SDR dongle. –

Comment: Im sampling over frequency 868MHZ and sample the radio At 2048000 , the IQ samples data I save them to a file type of dat, I enter that file into matlab and I see the packets , Im trying to detect the start of my packets by xcross corelation with my syncword(syncword is constant for every packet) , I did a demodulator (two matched filter) for detecting the data at 868khz with given deviation 100khz –

Comment: what should I do in order to detect the start of my every RF packet? Im trying to find xcross corelation according to my syncword(it's constant) but not succeeding to see the peak of corelation where there's syncword, I guess my two matched filter(demodulator) isn't good .. so could you help me what should I do in order to detect the start of my packets in matlab?maybe the length of my two matched filter /the two exponent(see matlab code please) must be on the size of symbol rate(50)?thanks alot!!

Comment: can you share a link to your data and your sinc word?

Comment: @DanBoschen Hi dan, sorry for late reply but didn't notice your reply until now, could you attach me your gmail? I cant upload the file here because it's a raw IQ samples data and it's relatively big , so Im going to share with you my file over drive .. thanks alot!

Comment: @DanBoschen , no need for your mail, attaching here my dat file: https://transferxl.com/08v4CV1YL8y5r8

Comment: @DanBoschen the file is relatively big because it has the samples that Im sampling by my dongle, those samples are the raw IQ samples data , if you enter this file in matlab you would see the second photo that I attached in my thread ( you would see packets .. )

Comment: @DanBoschen the file called fm.dat , I uploaded to my thread above what's my syncword that I transmit, also attached for your my matlab code for opening fm.dat file  , thanks for any help

Comment: Hi @DanBoschen forget please from the previous fm.dat file that I attached above, Im attaching new one over here : https://transferxl.com/08v7DDFqMtBPKY my syncword I attached it above on the thread, frequency that I transmt is 868MHZ , deviation 100KHZ, symbol rate 50KBAUD.

Comment: @DanBoschen would be much appreciated if you could help !!! , thanks alot.

Comment: I may have some time this weekend, nothing until then I'm afraid

Comment: @DanBoschen appreciated!!

Comment: @DanBoschen any update? thanks alot

Comment: I just downloaded your file- I will be back this evening and will look closer, but your syncword is FF00FF00? (It's not a very good sync word since it does not have good autucorrelation properties for synchronization- but I still should be able to find it) I also don't see in your MATLAB code in your question how you correlate to this pattern?