# Calculating the bit period

Tags: digital-communications, noise, cross-correlation, bitdepth

I want to calculate the bit period in my RF packets that I transmit them with 50Kbaud (Symbol rate=bit rate in my case) , how can I calculate the bit period?

Comment: The bit period is the time duration of one bit-- if the symbol rate is the bit rate, then the symbol rate is the inverse of the time duration. Is that what wasn't clear to you or something else?

Comment: @DanBoschen Yes exactly that's wasn't clear , you mean that 1/(50Kbaud) gives me the bit period .. ? but per what second or ms?

Answer (score 2):

50 KBaud means the symbol rate is 50 KHz (and in the OP's case the bit rate with 1 bit per symbol). The units of Hz is 1/sec. So the duration of each bit (the bit period) is simply

$$t_p = \frac{1}{50,000} = 20 \mu\text{s}$$

Comment: APPRECIATED! and one more thing that's confusing me which it's really not making me to progress ! , I send RF packets in frequency 868MHZ and symbol rate 50KHZ (symbol rate=bit rate) , deviation is 100kHZ , so once I transmit by cc1350 hardware of texas instrument, and Im sampling those IQ SAMPLES DATA (raw data) by a sampler called SDR dongle.

Comment: Im sampling over frequency 868MHZ and  sample the radio At 2048000 , the IQ samples data I save them to a file type of dat, I enter that file into matlab and I see the packets , Im trying to detect the start of my packets by xcross corelation with my syncword(syncword is constant for every packet) , I did a demodulator (two matched filter) for detecting the data at 868khz with given deviation 100khz

Comment: see here please https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68347/find-syncword-pattern-in-signal-using-correlation

Comment: what should I do in order to detect the start of my every RF packet? Im trying to find xcross corelation according to my syncword(it's constant) but not succeeding to see the peak of corelation where there's syncword, I guess my two matched filter(demodulator) isn't good .. so could you help me what should I do in order to detect the start of my packets in matlab? thanks alot!!

Comment: Hi Ryan- We are encouraged to not have a back and forth discussion in the comments, and your comments are specific to another question so better if you just put those details in your question not here. Thanks!